# Solve the following equation for x and y:

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^2 = y^2 + xy + 5$, where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers.

Here is what I have so far:

1. $x \neq y$ (from the equation).
2. $x$ is always odd (using the equation and assuming $2$ cases - $y$ is odd or $y$ is even).
3. Solving for the equation as a quadratic in $y$, $5x^2 - 20 \geq 0$ and a perfect square.

I feel I am missing a crucial point which will guide me towards a solution.

Hint please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by $4$. 
$$4x^2=4y^2+4xy+20$$

$$5x^2=(2y+x)^2+20$$

So, try to solve $$5x^2=z^2+20$$

$z$ must be multiple of $5$. So put $z=5a$ to get $$x^2-5a^2=4$$

This is a [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) with a solution $x=3, a=1$. From this and a minimal solution of $$A^2-5B^2=1,$$

say $A=9, B=4$, you can generate all solutions, and return to the original variables to get the solutions for the original equation.

Answer (score 3):

I like Conway's graphical method for these, the quadratic form is $f(x,y) = x^2 - xy- y^2,$ and we are looking for the value $5.$ As you can see, these happen when $y,x$ are consecutive Lucas numbers, $x$ is the larger one. I will need to look this up, there is something about odd/even indices as well. Alright, looked it up, the solutions with natural numbers are
$$  x = L_{2n}, \; \; y = L_{2n-1}; \; \; \; \; \; \;  n \geq 1 $$

See chapter 1 in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf

Let's see, Conway likes the letter $h$ for the little blue numbers labelling edges, the arrow points in the direction of increasing form value. He likes $a,b$ for the values, and two values $a,b$ on either side of an edge $h$ denote the quadratic form $a x^2 + h x y + b y^2$ or  $a x^2 - h x y + b y^2$  which is "equivalent" to the original. Our original is $x^2 - xy - y^2$ as that arrow points left, we see that $x^2 + xy - y^2,$ $x^2 + 3xy + y^2,$ and $x^2 + 5 xy + 5 y^2$ are equivalent to that. So is $5 x^2 + 5 xy + x^2.$

Conway does not generally draw in the $x,y$ coordinates of a point, i did that in green. Conway prefers to write those as vectors $e_1$ or $e_2.$ My way  is done in another book, by Stillwell. Finally, neither author forces the diagram to show the automorphism group, but, for MSE, that seems an important aspect.

[image]

What is traditionally called the **automorphism group** of the quadratic forms tells us that if we have a solution $x^2 - x y - y^2 = 5,$ then we get another one from
$$ (2x+y, x+y).  $$ This is the matrix product
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2x+y \\
x+y
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The matrix 
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has determinant $1,$ and trace $3.$ So, Cayley-Hamiltion says
$$ A^2 - 3 A + I = 0,  $$ or
$$ A^2 = 3 A - I .  $$
This tells us that, if we put the solutions $(x_n, y_n),$ we have
$$ x_{n+2} = 3 x_{n+1} - x_n, $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 3 y_{n+1} - y_n $$
as identities in the separate variables. these lead quickly to confirmation of the Lucas property.

Comment: Brilliant... Thoroughly enjoyed the Conway paper

Comment: I can't seem to figure out where are the $a$ and $b$ values in your picture. If all the blue numbers are the $h$ for the $hxy$ part in the quadratic, and the pink numbers are the values of $x^2 - xy - y^2$ when you plug in the green numbers as the $x$ and $y$ values, how do you obtain the $a$ and $b$ values from this picture?

Comment: Also how did you find $(2x + y, x +y)$ (and subsequently the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$)?

Comment: @user130018 $a,b$ are the pink values, on opposite sides of an edge which will be labelled $h.$ The form depicted is $a x^2 + h x y + b y^2.$ There is a certain degree of ambiguity, it might be $a x^2 - h xy + b y^2.$ Or, by rotating the picture, $b x^2 + h xy + a y^2.$ Glad you are trying to work this out.

Comment: @user, wesee a little identity matrix, one column vector in green with entries 1,0; with pink value 1. Below it and slightly left, a column with entries 0,1; value -1. Put the columns side by side in the correct oreder you get an identity matrix. Move immediately to the right, we see a column 2,1, with value 1; below it, column 1,1, value -1. I really should have drawn in the little blue arrow pointing left, that shows that this is the first perfect copy of the original form (with blue $h$ arrow pointing the same way). Put the two column vectors side by side in the proper order, you get it.