# Completeness proofs for the solutions of Diophantine Equations

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In general, what are the strategies for showing the completeness of a solution set for Diophantine Equations?

For example, take the $\textit{Pell-type}$ equation $x^2 - dy^2 = a$. Say, you have a set of solutions $\lbrace (u,v) \rbrace$ and say that $\epsilon$ is the $\textit{fundamental unit}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$. Then what is the easiest way to show that all the solutions are generated by $\lbrace\epsilon^n(u+\sqrt{d}v) \rbrace$ and that there are $\textit{no others}$?

As a slightly more intricate example, take the case of Mordell's Equation: $y^2 = x^3 - 13$. Assuming that $y+\sqrt{-13}$ was a cube in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-13})$ allowed me to find the solutions $(x,y) = (17,\pm 70)$, but in order to show that there were no others, I had to show that the sum and product of ideals:

$(y+\sqrt{-13})+(y-\sqrt{-13}) = \mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-13})$ and $(y+\sqrt{-13})\cap(y-\sqrt{-13}) = (y+\sqrt{-13})(y-\sqrt{-13}) = (x^3)$

Which I reckon allowed me to justify the assumption using the $CRT$.

Another interesting thing I found useful to keep track of from Keith Conrad's fantastic blurbs is parity. I also found a Theorem (whose proof I do not know) in one of Pete Clark's expositions that could be useful. (Theroem $8$ in [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/4400MordellEquation.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/4400MordellEquation.pdf))

But besides this, are there any other strategies one can use to learn more about a solution set? For instance, when can we ascertain whether or not it's finite? Are there any applications of the class number of the field here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your claim on the Pell equation is incorrect. On the other hand, there is a finite set of solutions such that your process generates all solutions.

Comment: @Will My apologies. What I think I really meant was: once you have a finite set of solutions, how do you check that you can now generate all of them?

Comment: I made a CW answer which is just a list of links here that I have answered. Maybe start on the more recent and go backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The only strategy I know of uses the group structure of the points. On integral points on curves of genus $0$, sch as the Pell equation, you have a group structure coming essentially from the multiplication of algebraic numbers; and on elliptic curves, which are curves of genus $1$, you have a group structure on the set of rational points. There is little you can do in terms of strategies if your variety does not have a group structure.

Now if you have a finite set of points, you can use ascent to produce (in general) infinitely many: given $P$ and $Q$ you can form linear combinations 
$aP + bQ$ using the group law. For showing that these are all you use infinite descent: the group law allows you to show that the existence of an additional  solution implies the existence of a point $R$ that is in a very precise sense "smaller" than those you already have (the technical term is called "height"). This reduces the task to a brute force search.

Both for curves of genus $0$ and $1$ there is an associated $L$-function $L(s)$  whose behavior at certain values ($s = 0$, $s = 1$ etc.) allows you to predict whether there are finitely or infinitely many integral (genus $0$) or rational (genus $1$) solutions. In both cases, you can use heavy machinery (cyclotomic units; Heegner points)  to produce a subgroup of finite index if the group in question has rank $1$. This again exploits the underlying group structure.

There are, as you have said, direct methods of obtaining integral points on curves of genus $1$ using algebraic number theory, but these become technical very quickly and reduce to solving sets of Thue equations. This is a completely different idea, since here you do not gain anything from knowing a few solutions. Indeed, the integral points do not have a group structure in this case.

Answer (score 0):

CW just a list

[Another quadratic Diophantine equation: How do I proceed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81917/another-quadratic-diophantine-equation-how-do-i-proceed/144794#144794)

[How to find solutions of $x^2-3y^2=-2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228356/how-to-find-solutions-of-x2-3y2-2/228405#228405)

[Generate solutions of Quadratic Diophantine Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342284/generate-solutions-of-quadratic-diophantine-equation/345128#345128)

[Finding all solutions of the Pell-type equation $x^2-5y^2 = -4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512621/finding-all-solutions-of-the-pell-type-equation-x2-5y2-4/512649#512649)

[how to solve binary form $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=m$, for integer and rational $ (x,y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739752/how-to-solve-binary-form-ax2bxycy2-m-for-integer-and-rational-x-y/739765#739765)  ::::  69   55

[Find all integer solutions for the equation $|5x^2 - y^2| = 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742181/find-all-integer-solutions-for-the-equation-5x2-y2-4/756972#756972)

[Maps of primitive vectors and Conway's river, has anyone built this in SAGE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078450/maps-of-primitive-vectors-and-conways-river-has-anyone-built-this-in-sage/1078979#1078979)

[Infinitely many systems of $23$ consecutive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091310/infinitely-many-systems-of-23-consecutive-integers/1093382#1093382)

[Solve the following equation for x and y:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132187/solve-the-following-equation-for-x-and-y/1132347#1132347)  <1,-1,-1>

[Finding integers of the form $3x^2 + xy - 5y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers, using diagram via arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132799/finding-integers-of-the-form-3x2-xy-5y2-where-x-and-y-are-integers)

[Small integral representation as $x^2-2y^2$ in Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221178/small-integral-representation-as-x2-2y2-in-pells-equation/1221280#1221280)

[Solving the equation $ x^2-7y^2=-3 $ over integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404023/solving-the-equation-x2-7y2-3-over-integers/1404126#1404126)

[Solutions to Diophantine Equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599211/solutions-to-diophantine-equations/1600010#1600010)

[How to prove that the roots of this equation are integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667323/how-to-prove-that-the-roots-of-this-equation-are-integers/1667380#1667380)

[Does the Pell-like equation $X^2-dY^2=k$ have a simple recursion like $X^2-dY^2=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719280/does-the-pell-like-equation-x2-dy2-k-have-a-simple-recursion-like-x2-dy2)

[If $d>1$ is a squarefree integer, show that $x^2 - dy^2 = c$ gives some bounds in terms of a fundamental solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737385/if-d1-is-a-squarefree-integer-show-that-x2-dy2-c-gives-some-bounds-i)